# Self-hosted meme generator

Tags: linux, open-source, web-apps, image-editor, self-hosted

I’m looking for a Web app (FLOSS and for self-hosting on a Linux server) that lets me add text to images. Fast and without hassle. I don’t want a full-featured image editor.

Examples:

- [imgur.com Meme Generator](https://imgur.com/memegen)
- [imgflip.com Meme Generator](https://imgflip.com/memegenerator)

Desired workflow/features:

1. **Choose one of the uploaded images.** The tool should offer a way to upload new ones. Formats: at least PNG and JPG.
2. **Add text in a WYSIWYG mode.** Ideally it would allow: choosing the font size/family/color; moving the text freely; creating different blocks of text.
3. **Download the edited image.**  It may also save the edited image on my server, but then it must use a different directory. If it saves them on the server, it would be nice to have a kind of browser to see all created images.

Comment: If we omit the WYSIWYG requirement you can do that with a few lines of PHP and GD/Imagemagick magic.